# Paypal webhook receivers asp

Tags: asp.net, rest, webhooks, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to create a webhook receiver using .asp for paypal. I have followed the minuscule amount of documentation paypal but can't receive webhooks.
I have created a web api project, installed the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Paypal` receiver and set up routes and a handler class to handle the webhook but all I keep getting are 500 internal server errors. 
I have yet to find an example of anyone doing this anywhere, does anyone have any pointers or more documentation or even if the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Paypal` works? I have seen examples for github and slack receivers but the same doesn't seem to work for paypal.

Update: I am now able to receive webhook although I get the message "The WebHook verification request must contain a 'code' query parameter". I have tested this both by using the simulated event and setting up sandbox webhooks and either way it doesn't not send across a code with the request. Any ideas of a way around this.

Further Update with solution: Turns out I was missing the webhook.id application setting in the paypal config so it was never validating the Id.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was missing the webhook.id application setting in the paypal config so it was never validating the Id.